# Exponentiation by Squaring (Project Euler 99) Tips on my solution

Tags: c++, computation

Here is the problem I am talking about
http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=99

My code will compile and run correctly. I am guessing the computation is where it is messing up. It is telling me that line number 633 is the largest (which project euler says is incorrect).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int poww(int base, int exp);
int main()
{
    //ignore messy/unused variables. I am desperate 
    int lineNumber = 0;
    string line; 
    int answerLine = 0;
    int max =0;
    int lineNum = 0;
    int answer =0;
    ifstream inFile;
    size_t location;
    string temp1,temp2;
    int tempMax = 0;
    int base,exp = 0;
    inFile.open("C:\\Users\\myYser\\Desktop\\base_exp.txt");
    while(getline(inFile,line))
    {
        lineNumber++;
        location = line.find(",");
        temp1 = line.substr(0,(int(location)));
        temp2 = line.substr((int(location)+1),line.length());
        //cout << temp1 << " " << temp2 << endl;
        base = atoi(temp1.c_str());
        exp =  atoi(temp2.c_str());
        tempMax= poww(base,exp);

        if (tempMax > max){
            max = tempMax;
            answer = base;
            answerLine = lineNumber;
        }

    }


    cout << answer << " " << answerLine;

    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
int poww(int base, int exp)
{
    int result = 1;
    while (exp)
    {
        if (exp & 1)
            result *= base;
        exp >>= 1;
        base *= base;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: You need to define "incorrect."

Comment: @tedled? What is incorrect? It cannot compile? It crashes? It works but not properly? It blows fire when you run it? Please be specific about your problem.

Comment: Added. "My program says that line number 633 is the greatest".

Comment: `ignore messy/unused variables` it's hard to...

Comment: I know. I seriously am incredibly annoyed and just trying to get this to work.

Comment: You're annoyed but you're not helping us answer your question. Pasting a link to a problem, your code, and some vague description of the output is far from helpful. How about providing a sample input, the expected output, and pointing to where you suspect the problematic code is.

Comment: And to get help from other people, it is in your best interest to clean up your code before posting.

Comment: The program takes no input. It is simply outputting the greatest sum line number which I already stated, 633. What else should I do sir?

Comment: Most Euler questions cannot be solved by naive approaches and brute forcing (at least not in 1 minute). You could use Python (which has arbitrary precision integers) but you might still find the program takes way to long to complete (perhaps longer than your lifetime).

Comment: Is the text file mentioned in the link you've posted not the input to the program? I would venture to guess that it is.

Comment: You *could* write a bignum class to solve the problem this way, but as the answers correctly state, you’re supposed to think of a much better algorithm.

Answer (score 5):

You're under-thinking this problem.

You need to come up with a way to scale down these numbers drastically so you can still compare them. In other words, you may want to look into a way of comparing how many digits the result will be.

A hint would be log(a^b) = b * log(a)

Comment: Yes, that is why I am using the exponentiation by squaring routine.

Comment: No, the point is that you need a larger number type to store the answer.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that an int can't hold 3 million digits. You need to come up with a way to scale down these numbers drastically so you can still compare them. In other words, you may want to look into a way of comparing how many digits the result will be.

Comment: An int can only hold 2^32 at a max, which isn't even remotely close to 3 million digits. Look into a solution involving logarithms. The whole point of this problem is that your solution has to compare the results of these exponents without actually computing them.

Comment: How can I compare results without computing?

Comment: By doing what I just said... Look into a method of estimating how many digits the result will be, and try comparing that. Or scale down the results drastically. You can also get a good estimate using logarithms.

Comment: Looking into logarithms? Will do.

Comment: Isn't estimating the number of digits one step more than necessary (computing x in 10 ** x = a ** b)? (The number of digits being `floor(x) + 1`?)

Comment: 10 ^ x = a ^ b. x * log(10) = b * log(a). x = b * log(a). Sort of what I had in mind, but yes. up'd

Answer (score 3):

A 32-bit int can only hold 2^32 values, and some of those magically turn negative at some point...